How to keep the Row Variable constant but change the Column in Excel?
Excel newbie, please forgive if its an easy question.
Say for example, I want to pull data from one sheet to the next, but the data is organized HORIZONALLY (i.e. B4, C4, D4, E4, etc).
Please advise.
When I put a $ in front of the 4 (to keep that ROW) and drag the field hoping it'll go to C, then D, etc. it doesn't.
I know when I put a $ in front of the B, it holds the B, and then pulls B5, B6, B7, B8, etc. But this would be going VERTICALLY down data.

Use the transpose function. (Assuming the sheet with horizontal data is called Sheet1.)
=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!B4:E4)

